# search between two dates, if exists - django - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to send two dates from template to backend through ajax response , in order to check if the two date exists or not! if not exists then return the entire data, but if exists just return the data between that two range

```
def dateTimePrice(request):
   start = request.GET.get('from')
   end = request.GET.get('to')
   print(start,end)#
   if start and end:
        datetimes = ImeiInvoice.objects.filter(invoice__created_at__range=(start,end)).annotate(
            total_price=Sum(
                (F('price')) - F('discount'),output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3))
        ).annotate(
            total_quantity=(
                Count('pk')
            )
        ).aggregate(
            all_price=Sum(F('total_price')),
            all_qnt=Sum(F('total_quantity'))
        )
    
   else:
        datetimes = ImeiInvoice.objects.all().annotate(
            total_price=Sum(
                (F('price')) - F('discount'),output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3))
        ).annotate(
            total_quantity=(
                Count('pk')
            )
        ).aggregate(
            all_price=Sum(F('total_price')),
            all_qnt=Sum(F('total_quantity'))
        )
return JsonResponse(datetimes,safe=False)

@login_required
def dateTimePriceTemp(request):
    return render(request,'myapp/datetimes.html')
```

and here is my GET form, to get the two date from

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const spinner = document.getElementById('spinnerDateTimePrice')
    const start_date = new Date($('#from').val());
    const end_date = new Date($('#to').val());
    console.log(start_date)
    console.log(end_date)
    if(start_date && end_date){
        data={
        'from':start_date,
        'to':end_date            
        }
    }
        function dateTimePrices(){        
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'/prices/dateTime/data',
                data:data,                
                success:function(data){
                    const datetimes = data;
                    var k = '<tbody>';
                    if(datetimes){
                        k+= '<tr>';
                            k+= '<td>' + datetimes["all_qnt"] + '</td>';
                            k+= '<td>' + datetimes['all_price'] + '</td>';

                        k+= '</tr>'                    
                    }else{
                        k+= '<td class="p-2 text-xs border border-purple-900 md:text-base textpurple" colspan=6>found nothing</td>'
                    }
                    k+='</tbody>'
                    document.getElementById('datetime_list').innerHTML = k        
                }                
            })        
        }    
        dateTimePrices();    
})
```

```html
    <form action="" method="GET">

        <div class="col-11 p-1 mt-1 mx-auto text-center row rtl ">
            <p class="col-12 col-sm-6 mx-auto text-left row">
            <img src="icons/date.svg" class="ml-1" alt="">  
            from  
            <input type="date" class="form-control col-9 mr-1" name="from" id="from"> 
            </p> 
            
            <p class="col-12 col-sm-6 mx-auto text-right row">
                <img src="icons/date.svg" class="ml-1" alt="">  
                to
                <input type="date" name="to" class="form-control col-9 mr-1" id="to">   
            </p>
            <button class="btn btn-info col-8 col-sm-5 col-md-3 mx-auto">search</button>
        </div> 
    </form>
```

i have to check if input dates exists then call the `data` variable into the ajax, but now even if i didnt any search still pretend like the date exists and return this error from server side

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“Invalid Date” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
> i much appreciate your helps ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the values from your GET parameters

```py
start = request.GET.get('from')
end = request.GET.get('to')
```

which are either `str/None` into datetime objects first.

Comment: in the console it just return invalid value, even we can get the date from console